# Gathering Data from Oracle view in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

In my project, I want to get some data from oracle database.

In the oracle database there are tables and views separately.

So I have connected to the database and tried gathering data from the views.

So I wrote this code to get the data. But, I'm returning an error in the `dt.Load(dr)` line that exception said **Specified Cast is not valid**

Can anyone explain me what this error means and how to avoid this?

This is first time I'm working with Oracle db.

```
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=TEST;Persist Security Info=True;UserID=app;Password=test;");
            con.Open();

            OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM P.INVENTORY_PART_IN_STOCK_UIV WHERE PART_NO = '90202-KPL-900D' and upper(P.Sales_Part_API.Get_Catalog_Group(CONTRACT, PART_NO) ) = upper('SPMB')";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: What column types are returned by the query?

Comment: @CaiusJard   strings,int,float,datetimes

Comment: @CaiusJard I realized the issue. I have tried it selecting one column. Then It returned the data. I think that issue came I selected * data from the table.

Comment: It sounds like one of the columns is some type that datatable doesn't support, like a geography, xml, blob.. I would try looking at all the different datatypes, and select one column from each of them, like `select someVarchar` `select somedatetime`, `select someint` .. it might narrow it down faster - start with unusual ones (because it's pretty standard that varchar, datetime, int etc are supported).. It's why I asked for an list of all the column types, so we can guess at the odd ones.. You could take your query, `CREATE VIEW tempview AS` from it, then DESCRIBE the view and post the list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle column types of NUMBER can represent more precision than .NET native type type Decimal.  I assume you are using an IFS database, and have faced the same issue.  I ended up with a solution using Entity Framework and mapped any NUMBER fields to a Double and converted locally to Decimal.  So far I haven't had any conversion issues in several years.

As pointed out in the comments, you can restrict your field list in your select statement, but you will struggle if you need to call a NUMBER type column.  Quick and dirty solution would be to use a `TO_CHAR` around any NUMBER columns and convert in your local code.